# Set unpublish status for a Component

Tags: 2009

Is there an API call in 2009 SP1 to set a component to unpublished similar to objPage.SetPublishedTo?

Comment: Nuno addresses this here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/setpublishedto-with-coreservice

Answer (score 3):

This is where, again, Tridion is technically correct... but it takes some mind-twisting to find it.

Components are not published - component presentations are. To set a component presentation as unpublished, use the ComponentTemplate's class "SetPublishedTo" method. I can't recall the details anymore, pretty sure you need to pass something like component URI + Publication Target and you're all set.